# Path navigation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i've been working on a website for a while using the Yelp API. And everytime i ant to import a component-class i stuggle at getting the correct filepath and it makes me insane. Can someone give me an easy explanation how navigating around in the folders with ease? I always have to fiddle until i get it and its time for me to learn this once in for all bc. it would save me so much time and energy.

This is what i usually use:

`import logo from './logo.svg';`

`import '../Business/Business';`

there is also other ways? like `/root/components/Business/Business`

pls be nice im still new to java , thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is any easy way around this. However there are few things that can be used to help.

Depending on text editor you use, this can be auto completed by the text editor itself. Visual studio code, for example has this plugin which is designed to help..
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ionutvmi.path-autocomplete

If this is no good then focus on the file to you are working on and where it is in the file system. 
If the file you are linking is in the same folder the the name of the file is fine.
If the folder is at a higher level just add ../ for every level it is higher.

I hope this helps.

Comment: helps a bit thank you, im using ATOM btw i moved away from dreamviewer

Comment: perhaps you could use this, i can't say i have ever used it but it looks promising for what you need and its for the ATOM editor.. https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-paths

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `resolve.modules` in webpack config

According to the **[documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules)**

> resolve.modules tells `webpack` what directories should be searched when resolving
>   modules.
>
> Absolute and relative paths can both be used, but be aware that they
>   will behave a bit differently.
>
> A relative path will be scanned similarly to how Node scans for
>   node_modules, by looking through the current directory as well as it's
>   ancestors (i.e. ./node_modules, ../node_modules, and on).
>
> With an absolute path, it will only search in the given directory.

So you would write

```
const path = require('path');

...
resolve: {
    modules: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/jsx'),
        'node_modules'
    ]
}
```

If you wish to resolve your files from `dirname/app/jsx` and `node_modules`

so essentially

```
import MyComponent from '/components/MyComponent.js'
```

will search `MyComponent` in `dirname/app/jsx/components/MyComponent.js'`